# python stdin eof

Tags: python, stdin, eof

How to pass python eof to stdin

here is my code

```
p = Popen(commd,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)
o = p.communicate(inputstring)[0]
```

when i run the commd in command line after i input the inputstring windows still expecting a Ctrl+Z  to finish accepting input.

How can I pass eof or Ctrl+Z in program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
p.stdin.close()
```

after p.communicate, finishes the input and sends EOF to commd.